# Yet another Data table Column Filter Text Input Value

Tags: yadcf

I am in over my head here but thought I'd ask this question anyway:

I am trying to create a table with a column of variable text inputs for an order form.  Ideally I want to filter only the rows that have a value in the input box (greater than zero). Filtering and searching data for this column doesn't work unless I assign a default value for the input which won't work for me.

Comment: dont you want to use a range_number / range_number_slider for filtering numbers? a jsbin with an example can help, because I don't understand your problem / what you trying to achieve

Comment: Here is my attempt. The "Values" column (3) consist of text input boxes. if I enter any values in any of the input boxes, their values are neither sorted or filtered. I want to be able to enter data in these boxes and then push a button to filter only the rows that have values in the input boxes.                       https://jsbin.com/nodedi/35/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: please use the latest js /css files for datatables / yadcf , you can make use of the https://rawgit.com/ to generate links to the yadcf js/css and make sure your jsbin will work propely before you post it here. I have to say that I never tried using inputs in table rows, but... before you expect yadcf to catch those values in its filters you must make sure that datatables itself can filter the inputs from its global filter AND the sort can sort them. only then you should expect from yadcf to filter them too (rememebr yadcf uses datatables api under the hood)

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I am in over my head here. I searched endlessly in datatables and could not find any reference to inputs in table rows and my post was unanswered.

Comment: My guess is that you can update the datatables on blur event of the inputs